# can't enter password in telnet login with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, telnet

If I telnet from windows command line there's no problem:

```
> telnet telehack.com
(... wait until a '.' appears)
. login
username? example
password? (examplepass) * * * * * * * 

Logged...
(...)
@ (This is the prompt when you are logged)
```

So with the shell I can login and do everything, and with the code in javascript written for nodejs I can do everything but enter the password. Then I'm able to: connect to host+port, enter 'login' command, enter 'example' username (which actually exists) and when I try to enter 'examplepass' (which actually exists too) the telnet server answers me with '* * * * * * *' but I'm not able to pass over that step. I'll provide the code, any help is appreciated.

```
var net = require('net');
var conn = net.createConnection(23, 'telehack.com');

conn.setEncoding('utf-8');

conn.on('connect', function() {  
  console.log('connected to the server');

  conn.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('' + data);
    if (data.indexOf('username') != -1) {
      conn.write('example\r\n');
    }
    if (data.indexOf('pass') != -1) {
      conn.write('examplepass\r\n');
    }
    if (data.indexOf("@") != -1) {
      conn.write('date\r\n');
    }
    if (data.slice(-1) == '.'){
      console.log('slice: '+data.slice(-1));
      //conn.emit('login');
      conn.write('login\r\n');

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out.](https://gist.github.com/telamon/1741019)

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(parseInt(process.argv[3]),process.argv[2],function(){
    client.setEncoding('utf8');
    console.log('Connected!!');
    client.on('data',function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    process.stdin.resume(); // Activate STDIN
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8'); // Set it to string encoding
    process.stdin.on('data',function(chunk){ // Pipe STDIN to Socket.out
        client.write(chunk);
    });
});
```

You have to re-enable stdin and send any data from stdin to the socket.

Comment: Oh thanks for the solution. This exact case was due to the Non negoatiation. The problem was that in that exact Telnet server you need to negotiate the comunication parameters: ECHO, WINDOW SIZE...So I needed to implement the negotiation. Thanks for the effort!!

Comment: @ederollora You bet. You should post the answer that solved your issue so people with the same problem know how to resolve their issue if they come across it.

Comment: Ok doing it tomrrow.Maybe not the best solution but I will share it.